# What is the best way to set object properties when filling a complex form in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, state-management

I'm new in React.  I have what seems like a standard task: fill in the form data about a user and send it to the server. The form is a set of components, such as: Basic information, Passport data, Hobbies, etc. + Save button.

I did it in the following way. There is a `class` describing the model. When creating a component, I create an instance of this `class` in `useRef`. Further, I pass this `model` variable to all child components through their props. Model properties are populated in components. So when I click on the `Save` button I have the model properties filled in. [Here's an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-4fpzky).

Please tell me, is this a good approach for filling in the data of a complex object? Maybe it's better to do it different way? Are there any best practices? Maybe I should use redux for this task?

**model.ts**

```
 class Model {
      // Component 1
      firstName: string;
      lastName: string;
    
      // Component 2
      passport: string;
      address: string;
    }
    
    interface IComponent {
      model: Model;
    }
    
    export { Model, IComponent };
```

**index.tsx**

```
export const App: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () =>
{
 const model = useRef<Model>(new Model());

 const save = () =>{
   console.log(model.current);
 }

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Component1 model={model.current} />
    <Component2 model={model.current} />
    <button onClick={save}>Сохранить</button>
  </React.Fragment>
);
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Component1.tsx**

```
export const Component1: React.FunctionComponent<IComponent> = ({ model }) => {

  const [firstNameValue, setFirstNameValue] = useState(model.firstName);
  const [lastNameValue, setLastNameValue] = useState(model.lastName);

  const changeFirstName = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      model.firstName = e.target.value;
      setFirstNameValue(e.target.value);
  }

  const changeLastName = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      model.lastName = e.target.value;
      setLastNameValue(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
  <React.Fragment>
   <div>
    <label htmlFor="firstName">FirstName:</label>
    <input name="firstName" value={firstNameValue} onChange={changeFirstName} />
   </div>
   <div>
    <label htmlFor="lastName">LastName:</label>
    <input name="lastName" value={lastNameValue} onChange={changeLastName}/>
   </div>
  </React.Fragment>);
};
```

**Component2.tsx**

```
export const Component2: React.FunctionComponent<IComponent> = ({ model }) => {
   const [passportValue, setPassportValue] = useState(model.passport);
   const [addressValue, setAddressValue] = useState(model.address);

  const changePassport = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      model.passport = e.target.value;
      setPassportValue(e.target.value);
  }

  const changeAddress = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      model.address = e.target.value;
      setAddressValue(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
  <React.Fragment>
   <div>
    <label htmlFor="passport">Passport:</label>
    <input name="passport" value={passportValue} onChange={changePassport} />
   </div>
   <div>
    <label htmlFor="address">Address:</label>
    <input name="address" value={addressValue} onChange={changeAddress}/>
   </div>
  </React.Fragment>);
};
```

Comment: I'm working on an answer for this, but is there any reason in your specific use case that `Model` should have to be a `class` instance rather than an `interface`?  Especially since we are starting with all properties empty, I really would not use a `class` here.  You can create the `class` from the data when you call `onSubmit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend redux for this.  Redux solves the problem of making data available to the whole app, but our form is self-contained so it's not the right tool for the job.  If the form started getting really complex, you might think about using a `Context` for the form, but that's unnecessary right now.

What you want is for the form state to be stored at the top-level of the form and passed down to specific components.  You don't want the individual components to managing their own state.

I can't see a good use case for using a `class` for the form data.  You want to store your data in an `interface`.  If you need a class later on, you can construct it from the interface of data.

```
export interface Model {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  passport: string;
  address: string;
}
```

Instead of using `useRef` to store a class instance, we use `useState` which allows up to both store an update the form data.  My first instinct was that the state type would need to be `Partial<Model>` since we are starting out with all of the fields empty.  But since these are all `string` fields, we can create an `initialModel` that has empty strings for each property and is a complete `Model`.

```
const initialModel: Model = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  passport: "",
  address: ""
};

const [model, setModel] = useState<Model>(initialModel);
```

`Component1` and `Component2` need to get the current `model` as a prop and they also need to get a way to update the model.  We could pass `setModel` as a prop and that would be fine, but we'd end up repeating logic because we would have to write `{...model,` every time we call `setModel` to update a single property.

Instead we can create and pass down a helper function that updates a single property.  This function takes the name of the `property` and the new `value` that we are setting it to.

```
const setProperty = (property, value) => {
  setModel({
    ...model,
    [property]: value
  });
};
```

I don't know how advanced your typescript knowledge is.  If `Model` had different fields with different value types, we would want to use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) to ensure that the type of the value matched the property.

```
export type SetPropertyFunction = <T extends keyof Model>(
  property: T,
  value: Model[T]
) => void;
```

But since all of our values are `string` here, we can get away with something simpler.

```
export type SetPropertyFunction = (
  property: keyof Model,
  value: string
) => void;
```

The props that our sub-components will receive are the `model` and the `setProperty` callback.

```
export interface ComponentProps {
  model: Model;
  setProperty: SetPropertyFunction;
}

export type FormComponent = React.FunctionComponent<ComponentProps>;
```

**Complete App Component**

```
export const App: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () => {
  const [model, setModel] = useState<Model>(initialModel);

  const setProperty: SetPropertyFunction = (property, value) => {
    setModel({
      ...model,
      [property]: value
    });
  };

  const save = () => {
    console.log(model);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Component1 model={model} setProperty={setProperty} />
      <Component2 model={model} setProperty={setProperty} />
      <button onClick={save}>Сохранить</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Now for `Component1` and `Component2`.  They no longer manage any internal state.
They can get the `value` for each field from the model: `model.firstName`.  In the `onChange` handler, we call our `setProperty` helper with the name of the `property`.

```
const changeFirstName = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setProperty("firstName", e.target.value);
};

const changeLastName = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setProperty("lastName", e.target.value);
};
```

These callbacks are simple enough that we could write them inline, too.

```
onChange={e => setProperty("firstName", e.target.value)}
```

Our component now only handles presentation. This is [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), which is good!

**Complete Component1**

```
export const Component1: FormComponent = ({ model, setProperty }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="firstName">FirstName:</label>
        <input
          name="firstName"
          value={model.firstName}
          onChange={e => setProperty("firstName", e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="lastName">LastName:</label>
        <input
          name="lastName"
          value={model.lastName}
          onChange={e => setProperty("lastName", e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

[StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-bhdla6)